# Determine compiler used to create a given bytecode

Tags: solidity, evm, solc, compiler, vyper

### Context

The method that the solc compiler uses to set storage slots for a mapping is slightly different from how the [Vyper compiler does so](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/issues/769). In Vyper, it's `keccak256(slotMapping, key)`, while in Solidity it's `keccak256(key, slotMapping)`. Therefore, different logic is required for look-ups, depending on which compiler was used. I am trying to determine which compiler was used to generate a given compiled bytecode.

---

### Question

Without having the contract's source code and using only the RPC method `eth_getCode`, is there a way to confidently determine whether the solc or Vyper compiler was used?

### Constraints

I'm only interested in contracts compiled with solc or Vyper. I'm not concerned about other compilers at this moment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the **bytecode metadata**<sup>1</sup> to determine the smart contract language and the compiler version used to compile the bytecode. Both compilers include bytecode metadata by default<sup>2</sup>.

1. Get the runtime bytecode of a smart contract using `eth_getCode`.
2. Extract the bytecode metadata by counting either `n` bytes (Solidity) OR `n - 2` bytes (Vyper) backwards from the last two bytes of the bytecode, where the last two bytes of the bytecode are the length `n`.

For example, if the bytecode ends like this:

```
...04da03c68419056f81181800a16576797065728300030a0015
```

Then the metadata would be `03c68419056f81181800a16576797065728300030a` if it was compiled using `solc` or `8419056f81181800a16576797065728300030a` if it was compiled using `vyper`. To illustrate:

```
       ┌──────────────0x0015 bytes──────────────┐      Solidity
...04da03c68419056f81181800a16576797065728300030a0015
           └──────────0x0015 - 2 bytes──────────┘      Vyper
```

Or, in JavaScript:

```js
const bytecode = '...04da03c68419056f81181800a16576797065728300030a0015';
const metadataLength = parseInt(bytecode.slice(-4), 16);
const solcCBOR = bytecode.substring(bytecode.length - 4 - metadataLength * 2, bytecode.length - 4);
const vyperCBOR = bytecode.substring(bytecode.length - metadataLength * 2, bytecode.length - 4);
```

Unfortunately, since you won't know which compiler was used until you decode the metadata, you'll likely have to try both and see which one decodes successfully.

3. The bytecode metadata for both compilers is [CBOR](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8949.html)-encoded. You can use any CBOR decoder ([online example](https://cbor.me/)) to decode it. Solidity encodes an object that looks like this:

```
{"ipfs": h'1220A454FC5E914817178F216E41C3F677683CB5B09C52970CE54C207F250B3AB7BC', "solc": h'000813'}
```

And Vyper encodes something like this:

```
[1391, [24], 0, {"vyper": [0, 3, 10]}]
```

In either case, the bytecode metadata includes information about the both the programming language and the compiler version used (e.g., `solc v0.8.13` or `vyper v0.3.10` in the examples above).

References:

- [Solidity docs: "Encoding of the Metadata Hash in the Bytecode"](https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/metadata.html#encoding-of-the-metadata-hash-in-the-bytecode)
- [Vyper source code: `compile_ir.py`](https://github.com/vyperlang/vyper/blob/68da04b2e9e010c2e4da288a80eeeb9c8e076025/vyper/ir/compile_ir.py#L1222)

---

<sup>1</sup> The "bytecode metadata" (or "compiler metadata") is **different from the JSON metadata** that is produced from the `--metadata` flag. The bytecode metadata is directly encoded into the bytecode and is available on-chain (i.e., via `eth_getCode`) while the JSON metadata is a separate file that must be hosted somewhere off-chain.

<sup>2</sup> A developer may configure the compiler to *not* include bytecode metadata using the `--no-cbor-metadata` flag for `solc` or the `--no-bytecode-metadata` flag for `vyper`.